# Does "-5 on your next combat" include helping someone?

Tags: munchkin

So this was a huge dispute a while back and still is. If you play a curse or trap on someone that gives a “-5 on your next combat” would you consider your next combat to be the one on your next turn or could you help someone else in combat and then get rid of the curse? From my thinking, since you had to add that -5 to you combat strength when helping someone, it would go away but others think that since it says YOUR next combat it specifically has to be on your next turn. Please help us settle this!

Answer (score 8):

The [Official Munchkin FAQ](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/) states:

> **Q. If a card that affects "your next combat" is played on you during a combat, does it affect THAT combat, or the next one you're in?**
>   *A. If the combat is still unresolved (and obviously it is, because people are still playing cards on you for it), then that combat is the "next" one. Most Munchkin games say this explicitly in the rules, but it's true even if we left it out by mistake.*

That seems quite clear. The next combat to resolve  in which "you are a participant".

Comment: This quote is about the card being played on someone mid-combat, not about helping someone else in combat. It's therefore useless at answering the question.